# Playing from the start without loading whole file + Ability to stream unloaded parts of a file

Tags: jwplayer

I have JWPlayer version: 5.8.2011

When I stream files player needs to load a file completely, until it starts to play, I am trying to find a way to make it start play a file right from the start and keep on loading as well. I also need another thing.

Another thing that I am trying to achieve, is an ability to stream different parts of a file, let's say 3:20 is not loaded yet, but when I click on it I want player to start playing 3:20 immidiately and load from it.

There are such things almost everywhere on internet, and I look at it as just normal requirements that a website should provide, I could not achieve this yet

```
jwplayer("stream").setup({
    flashplayer: "http://xxx/views/default/js/jwplayer/player.swf",
    provider:"video",
    file: "http://xxx/stream/tcNEJlYrSj2WsU5U",
    image: "http://xxx/stream/sYPCUgIMYCMsP3RM",
    screencolor: "000000",
    width: "640",
    height: "360",
    stretching: "uniform",
    skin: "http://xxx/views/default/js/jwplayer/skins/lulu.zip",
});
```

I am having a hosting at Fatcow.com, please tell me things that I need to ask a hosting provider to provide for me if there are any requirements to have on server from them too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file needing to be downloaded entirely before it can be played back is an issue in regards to how the file was encoded.

If your MP4 files cannot be seeked before they are completely downloaded, you will have to fix the MOOV atom (it contains the seeking information) located at the end of your video. Use this little application to parse your videos and add the necessary cue points.

http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Comment: No problem, let me know if that tool helps. Another way to fix this would be to encode using HandBrake (http://handbrake.fr/), and enable "web optimized" when encoding.

Comment: yes It helps. just rewrited a file on ftp and plays from the start. bad thing is that my hosting wont support any application that can do such thing, executing files or installing python scripts that do this is also not supported so I have to reupload everything. but in matters of desktop solution `QTIndexWrapper` is really nice. I would recommend it.